# How to design an amplifier to meet particular specifications

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, electrical

I need to specify the (W/L) ratio of transistors and the value of the current source in an amplifier as shown in this picture
[image]

so that these specifications are met:
[image]

*the height of the input step for evaluating settling time is 0.25v.

I tried to approach it by first using the settling time to evaluate slew rate and wt and then using the approximation of wt = wp*gain but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each transistor has a specific purpose.

Define the operating voltage for each transistor.

Define the needed current for each transistor.

And each transistor may need a specific transconductance, to assist certain circuit gains and bandwidths and output currents.

When you have defined the voltage and the current, then you can compute the W/L.